# Azure Devops: build Xcode tasks fails when using manual signing option

Tags: xcode, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Note:[Question copied from](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/305275/build-xcode-tasks-fails-when-using-manual-signing.html)

I am having trouble trying to get my Xcode task to build when I use manual signing when trying to build my iOS app. Everything in the process below works fine including installing the distribution certificate and distribution profile. However as soon as it hits the Xcode task it fails with the following error message:

### [error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65

If however I change my signing to project defaults everything works fine and the project builds.

What I would like to do eventually is create an app package and push it to AppCenter so that I can distribute. However I have been on with this for 2 weeks now trying many different configurations and reading lots of articles on the subject but still cannot get it to work.

I have a Sign & Build process that does the following:

**Installs Apple Certificate**

Certificate (P12): MyApp_Distribution.p12

Certificate (P12) password: $(P12password) - (set in variable field)

Keychain: Temporary Keychain

Certificate Signing Identity: blank

Install Apple Provisioning Profile

Provisioning profile location: Secure Files

Provisioning profile: Appstore_release.mobileprovision

Remove profile after build: checked

**CocoaPods** to update pods.

**Xcode**

Actions: build

Configuration: $(Configuration) (set in variable field - Release)

SDK: $(SDK) – (set in variable field - iphoneos)

Workspace or project path: projectName.xcworkspace

Scheme: projectName

Xcode version: Xcode 9

**Signing & Provisioning**

Signing style: Manual signing

Signing identity: iPhone Distribution: companyName (companyID)

Provisioning profile UUID: $(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)

Provisioning profile name: name of provisioning profile as displayed in Xcode ie MyApp Release Adhoc

**Package options**

Create app package: not ticked

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can set `system.debug= true` to get more detailed log.